# c# Generate c# code before compilation/buil (Like maven plugin in java)

Tags: c#, code-generation, pre-build-event

I have a projet in c# .net.
I need to hook the "pre build" event so I can run a c# class that will generate other c# class to the same project.
I know that in java you can generate source code using maven plugin, is it possible in .net?

Thanks.

Comment: There are [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) templates, maybe that fits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two options:

1. Use [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)
2. Add a pre-build step to the build file.

T4 is the inbuilt way to do code generation (and widely used in ASP.NET MVC scaffolding and Entity Framework type generation). However T4 doesn't directly support compile time generation. It does either design time – with the developer triggering (re-)generation – or runtime generation; (third party tools can add compile time generation).

---

Adendum (after 6 years): NuGet packages like [Clarius.TransformOnBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild/) can also do this.

A custom MSBuild task (including running an external program) can be used to create code which is then included in the compile. In the simplest cases the "pre-build" setting of a project can be used (the Build Events tab of the project properties). Directly working in MSBuild (and a `.csproj` is a MSBuild file) gives more flexibility.

Comment: T4 does support compile time generation of C# code, using the Tangible T4 Editor (see my answer above).

Comment: @Gravitas OK added a note that third party tools can add compile time generation.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [Tangible T4 Editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html). Its a plugin for Visual Studio that exposes the built in [T4 Text Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) functionality so you can use it to auto-generate C# files. It enables support for compile time generation of C# code within Visual Studio.

I used this to convert a .xml file into 2,600 lines of C# at compile time. Now, if I change the .xml file, and recompile, it will automatically regenerate the correct C# code.

It works like magic, and is completely seamless.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx).